# Как сделать нажатие кнопки старт несколько раз?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать кнопку старт в телеграм боте рабочей на множество нажатий?Заранее благодарен

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def repeat_all_message(message):
    
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Individual /individual', parse_mode='Markdown')

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Family /family', parse_mode='Markdown')
```